# How to translate "associative movement"

Tags: vocabulary

How could we translate "associative movement" in Latin?

I know "association" is usually "consociatio", but what about the adjective?

"Associative movement" means (more or less) the fact that people tend to form associations.

An example: "Without pretending to be an exhaustive study of the associative fabric in the rural environment, this report concerns the participation of women in the **associative movement**."

Or: "This subsidy supports the businesswomen's **associative movement** of AFAEMME by means of the financing expenses of supporting staff."

Or: "By tracing the development of the **associative movement** since the early twentieth century, including the notorious fractiousness of associations, this chapter argues..."